# What do they mean by feedback

Tags: discussion, meta, feedback

The Privilege [Page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/participate-in-meta) at Meta Stack Overflow says

```
When should I visit meta ?
```

- to provide **feedback**
- to report a bug
- to suggest changes to the community
- to discuss how the site works

I know what is a bug and what are the suggestions, but why the feedback option is here too as this is already present in footer links. Is there any difference these two feedback options.

Comment: The feedback link in the footer just links to meta, so I don't know why you think there is a difference.

Comment: When you go to the users of you software and ask for feedback, what do _you_ mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that feedback in general is the ability to answer existing Meta questions and give your own opinion on things.

For example you can answer a feature request adding your opinion on it, which is a feedback. Might be positive or negative.

Same goes for discussions.

True feedback can be provided on announcements such as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center) which are posted to gain feedback in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Provide Feedback on how SO, it's operation, concepts, or just general usage on how everything is working...