# Add strings from the Moderator Agreement page into Transifex (or use existing keys)

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, moderator-agreement

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement

We, as mods, have to accept the new agreement. And on this page there are a lot of strings that were not translated:

1. Accept.
2. Decline.
3. Moderator Agreement.
4. ...

Even though these strings are in Transifex, it looks like they are not used.

Could you add those strings into Transifex or use the existing strings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The new moderator agreement is now live for moderators to accept across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350544/the-new-moderator-agreement-is-now-live-for-moderators-to-accept-across-the-netw) - For posts tagged "Announcement": "If anyone has questions about the agreement itself **or the rollout**, please post them as an answer.". That is essentially an announcement, even if not so tagged.

Comment: @Rob no, it's about agreement itself)

Comment: It may seem odd but on MSE (here) this *question* should be an ***answer*** (Feedback) on the **Question** listed as a duplicate. Examples and Instructions: [What do they mean by feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182944/282094), [New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/282094), [We're Implementing an "announcement" Tag for Direct Communication From the Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290662/282094) - that precedent has long been established.

Comment: While I got quite irate at a LJ expecting me to accept an agreement in russian... arn't all the agreements in english (and legal-like?), or is there a per language translation somewhere?

Comment: @Rob transifex has its own set of specialists and issues, so asking its own question, with the appropriate tags makes sense,

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't ask to translate agreement itself, I've asked to translate buttons/titles, etc)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek those agreements in English on all localized sites, they have never been translated.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek which begs the question: If you read it in English shouldn't you (lawyer hat on) reply in English - so Feedback about the Buttons is appropriate on the listed dupe. Indeed, asking a separate question to translate the agreement (which this question does not) would entail taking it to the Legal Team and having a (paid) Lawyer translate it into ***each*** supported language (and Stack Exchange had already said: "... no new foreign language sites, due to support (CM) costs."), so *that* idea is likely a non-starter.

Comment: @Rob It's inconsistent with the prior agreement, which prompted users to read the agreement in English but accept it in the site's language. Either this inconsistency should be fixed, or the team should state here that this was an intentional change.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, indeed nothing to do with the agreement is available in any language other than English; for legal reasons: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350859/282094