# Add notification text about new Moderator Agreement into Transifex

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, moderator-tools, localization, international-sites

Moderators should accept new Agreement. And there is notification about it.

[image]

But it's not localized, and there is no such string in the Transifex. Could you add it, so we will be able to translate it?

Comment: Don't we need all moderators to be able to speak english? How else are they going to accept the new moderator agreement?

Comment: @Luuklag  it's not about agreement translation, it's about localization of the interface. It should be consistent.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I'd say there is no need to translate it when this only applies to moderators, who also need to read the english moderator agreement in order to be able to accept that.

Comment: @Luuklag Considering the rest of the interface *is* localized and it's not that much work, I'd make the notification localized anyway. Whether or not the agreement itself should be translated is a different question. This notification is only the signpost.

Comment: As a note, this banner will only be up for one more week. It will be replaced by a different one for the last two weeks of the acceptance period (after a four-week period of having no banner).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These strings can't be added to Transifex because of how the banners are configured.

The moderator agreement itself is only available in English for legal reasons, so between that and the fact that they're up for a limited time, we decided not to translate the banners in this case.