# All references to the FAQ in close reasons should be changed to Help Center links

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, help-center

Close reasons still have links to the FAQ in them - these should be referred to as the Help Center, since that's what it is now.

- Not Constructive (emphasis obviously mine)

  > We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, **see the FAQ for guidance**.
- Off Topic (ditto)

  > Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the **scope defined in the FAQ**. Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope.
- Too Localized (...)

  > This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, **see the FAQ**.
- Not A Real Question (...)

  > It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, **see the FAQ**.

All of these should be changed to "see this Help Center topic" (or similar). Since, y'know, it's the Help Center, now, not the FAQ.

Comment: It should be noted that the links to the old FAQ do redirect to their relevant help center pages.

Comment: Damn, I missed the change from FAQ to help center?

Comment: @hjpotter http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center

Comment: And no one thought to mention it in [Recent changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161595/212576)?

Comment: @hjpotter92 it's still very new and at first was available only here on Meta for our review and feedback. I think that it went live on all sites only today.

Comment: @animuson: not entirely; the ones to `/faq#closed` do (after a page load, in a manner that is less compatible, but should still always work), but the "FAQ" link in the "off topic" item is now very difficult to use; it needs to be to http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/on-topic rather than to http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new help center did just go live in the past 12 hours. We're also getting ready to push out new close reasons, which will have updated language. (In case you missed the discussion of the new close reasons, [here's one about improving "not constructive" and NARQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv) - the bottom of the question links to the other pieces of the discussion.)

Since that's so close to going live, we're not going to make any changes to the current verbiage. The new close reasons will have the proper terminology, and I'll make sure whatever historical notices are remain with the old reasons are updated, too. It'll be inconsistent for a short time, but it's on my list to update soon. :)