# "contact us" in footer still leads to old help center

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, help-center, footer

The Help Center [went through a very major face lift](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182812/152859) recently and got a new URL.

All sites are now linking to it by "help" link both on top and in the bottom of every page.

However, the footer contains "contact us" link as well which leads to the old help center.

Doubt it's on purpose, all roads better lead to [Rome](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47380653,d.Yms&biw=1400&bih=941&q=Rome&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x132f6196f9928ebb:0xb90f770693656e38,Rome,%20Italy&gl=uk&sa=X&ei=59-uUarSA5DCswa4noCoAw&ved=0CKkBELYD). :)

Comment: Yes, but *which* Rome? I have lots of bronze broadswords that I could stand to sell!

Comment: @Andrew you're right, silly me! Updated my post now. Any Vorpal Sword to sell? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are aware of the problem and we consciously left it in for now.

It's a temporary measure while we simplify the old help center into a real contact us feature.

There are forms there that we want to keep but as a separate entity.

---

Edit: it's now done

Comment: Thanks. As for "contact us" why not simply http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The functionality of the old help center is due partly to the fact that it lists the most common issues people contact us about. Some of those things are problems users can solve themselves, so we do want to provide on-site instructions in those cases. For the rest, it speeds things up on our end if emails we receive have a clear title that identifies what type of issue is occurring. As Sklivvz said, we're looking to simplify things a little on that page to make it easier on everyone.

Comment: It's now fixed, feel free to mark [meta-tag:status-completed]. :)