# I lost my FAQ (link)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

It seems the link to the FAQ is gone from the top menu bar on multiple sites, at least Stack Overflow, The Workplace.

All of our users on The Workplace are now posting answers/questions which are low quality because they haven't read it since there is no link (obviously if the link is there they will read it, understand it, and adapt their posting appropriately...).

Help us please!

Comment: faq => help - all the info is in the help center.

Comment: In other words, we are no longer FAQing with our users.

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure how I feel about this change, "Help" is less of a "Please read" than "FAQ"

Comment: The biggest problem with FAQ on a Question and Answer site... is... what does it refer to: site usage or a list of questions that have been frequently asked...

Comment: It seems far more difficult to find the list of what is on topic under the new system.  I did finally manage to find it after some digging, but shouldn't that be one of the first things in the Help Center and easiest to find what is actually on topic for a site since it is the core of what makes a site.

Comment: I really don't like this change. It's much more difficult to find what privileges the reputation gives you now, for example.

Answer (score 5):

The Faq has been replaced with the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter).

So the help button is now the Faq button.

You can read this post: [Introducing a brand new, consolidated, Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center) for more information on the subject

Answer (score 1):

Recently the FAQ has been consolidated into the new Help center.

See this related post: [Introducing a brand new, consolidated, Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center)