# Magic links to helpcenter subsections

Tags: feature-request, magic-links

Could the magic links be updated so that we can link to help center subsections? In the past, `[faq#section]` used to work, now neither `[help#section]` nor `[help/section]` work.

Could this be added?

---

As per Nick's request, I'm starting a list of shortcuts that would be nice to have; besides the `[help#anchor]` → `/help/anchor` ones. Feel free to edit more in:

- `#benice` → [`#behavior`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) (preferably a section link to the "be nice" section)
- `#bounty` → [`#no-one-answers`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)
- `#promotion` →  [`#behavior`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) (preferably a section link)

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183131/replace-faq-magiclink-with-help

Comment: I am guessing here but I think this would already be in the works.

Comment: @AsheeshR: _Usually_ features like this aren't rolled out incrementally (because of the dogfooding incremental rollouts tend to break stuff),  so I'm not too sure of that :)

Comment: Currently, generated `[faq#section]` links do redirect to relevant Help Center pages. Example: [FAQ#dontask].

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, I know, but I'd like that for all help center pages.

Comment: Sure, I didn't say it was a solution. It is a workaround for the old FAQ links.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yep :)

Comment: So the way this works now is we take the hash and redirect it to the appropriate help section.  If you have specific helpful hashes that have a new destination, start a list here and we'll get any redirects that make sense in.

Comment: @NickCraver Great! :D Some of the older redirects would be nice -- `#benice` for the relevant section [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) is the only one I can think of right now.

Comment: @Manishearth recommend starting a list in the question and we'll come visit it in a few days - it's not my project but happy to help out :)

Comment: @NickCraver sure, no problem :) Started.