# We used to be able to do [faq#how-to-ask], what's the alternative with the new Help Center?

Tags: support, help-center, magic-links

Say I want to refer a user to **[/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**, With the older, `[faq]` syntax, I could have done it easily using a hash after the word "FAQ":

> Please check the [faq#how-to-ask]

How can I do the same with the new Help Center? Do I have to post a full `[description](link)` form? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Feature-request : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184718/magic-links-to-helpcenter-subsections