# Complete list of help center magic links

Tags: support, magic-links

Where is the complete, canonical list of magic links to the Help Center? The [list in Laura's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188238/134069) seems quite short.

Comment: Who can create magic links? I would love one for the [why not post an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that it is complete, because when balpha [created magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/259214), he didn't write more links than Laura (except of adding links to the tour).

Answer (score 50):

It would appear that nicael is correct, that's the complete list. Here's the most complete list of magic links I can find (both help center and other), from [Laura's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188238/134069) and the [balpha answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/259214) nicael linked to:

### Magic Links

- Characters within the magic links can be any mix of upper and lower case. Some, but not all, of the magic links will respect the case used in the magic link and use the same case for the link text. This is noted in the entry for those which respect case.
- On localized sites, the link text for each of the below magic links is localized.

#### Supported magic links in comments

- `[meta]` – links to the current site's Meta; link text is the site name (e.g. "Meta Super User"). Does nothing if the site doesn't have (or already is) a Meta site.
- `[main]` – like [meta], just the other way around (i.e. it doesn't work on main sites; only works on meta sites which have an associated main site).
- `[edit]` – links to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e. /posts/{id}/edit. Link text is "edit" (capitalization is respected).
- Help center links.  Link text for all of these is "help center":

  - `[help]` – links to the help center (/help).
  - `[meta-help]` – links to "What is meta?" (/help/whats-meta)
  - `[help/on-topic]` – links to "What topics can I ask about here?" (/help/on-topic).
  - `[help/dont-ask]` – links to "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" (/help/dont-ask).
  - `[help/behavior]` – links to "What kind of behavior is expected of users?" (/help/behavior).
- `[tour]` or `[about]` – links to (<main site>/tour). Link text is "tour" (capitalization is respected). Legacy magic link `[about]` is still supported.
- `[meta-tour]` or `[meta-about]` – links to (<meta site>/tour). These only work on meta sites. Link text is "tour" (capitalization is respected). Legacy magic link `[meta-about]` is still supported.
- `[ask]` – links to the "How to Ask" page. Link text is "How to Ask".
- `[what you are asking]` – links to the "How to Ask" page. Link text is "what you are asking".
- `[answer]` – links to the "How to Answer" page. Link text is "How to Answer".
- Links to the front page of Stack Exchange sites (link text is the site name):

  - `[so]` – links to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
  - `[su]` – links to [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
  - `[sf]` – links to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
  - `[metase]`/`[meta.se]` – links to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)
  - `[ubuntu.se]` – links to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)
  - `[mathoverflow.se]` – links to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)
  - `[a51]` – links to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com)
  - `[se]` – links to the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/)
  - Localized Stack Overflow sites can be linked as

    - `[es.so]` – links to [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)
    - `[ja.so]` – links to [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
    - `[pt.so]` – links to [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)
    - `[ru.so]` – links to [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)
  - All other Stack Exchange sites, except Stack Apps:

    - `[something.se]` – links to something.stackexchange.com, if that site exists. Link text is the site name.
    - `[sitename.meta.se]` or `[meta.sitename.se]` – links to a site-specific Meta site. Link text is "Meta <sitename>".
- `[chat]` – links to the current site's chat site (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ for SO, https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/ for Meta SE, https://chat.stackexchange.com/ everywhere else – that last one showing a list of active rooms from the referring site), the link text being "{site name} Chat".
- `[code block]` – links to the "Code and Preformatted Text" section of the Markdown Editing Help page (/editing-help#code). Link text is "code block".
- On Stack Overflow only:

  - `[English-only site]` – links to the (SO-only) Help Center page "[Can I ask a question in a language other than English?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions)". Link text is "English-only site".
  - `[help/sg]` – links to the (SO-only) Help Center page "[What is the Staging Ground?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-is-staging-ground)". Link text is "What is the Staging Ground?".
- On Stack Overflow and localized Stack Overflow sites (these do not work on the associated meta sites):

  - `[mcve]`, `[reprex]`, `[repro]`, `[mre]` and `[example]` – links to the [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) page for the site. Link text is "minimal reproducible example", or localized text on localized sites. Capitalization doesn't matter and is not respected.
- Links to specific tags. These work in questions, answers, comments, and chat – but in comments, they are just formatted like regular links, rather than appearing like tags. Link text is just the name of the tag. These will link to the specified tag, regardless of whether the tag actually exists:

  - `[tag:tag-name]` creates a link to the named tag on the main site, e.g [tag-name](/questions/tagged/tag-name). (Whether it's used on the main site or the meta site, the link will point to a tag on the main site.)
  - `[meta-tag:meta-tag-name]` creates a link to a tag on meta, e.g [meta-tag-name](/questions/tagged/meta-tag-name). (Whether it's used on the main site or the meta site, the link will point to a tag on the meta site.)
  - (On Meta Stack Exchange, which doesn't have a main site, `[tag:tag-name]` and `[meta-tag:tag-name]` work exactly the same way.)

#### Supported magic links in chat

In chat, only a limited subset of the magic links listed for comments work, plus one chat-specific magic link.

Chat supports the following magic links: `[meta]`, `[main]`, `[ask]`, `[answer]`, all the links to specific sites, and tag links (with tag formatting). Chat also adds `[chat-faq]`, which results in a link to /faq on the current chat database, with the link text "chat faq" (e.g. "[chat faq](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq)").

The tag magic links work as expected on [Stack Overflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and [Meta Stack Exchange Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/). However, on [Stack Exchange Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/), the chat room in which you use the magic link must be associated with a specific Stack Exchange site, and will take on the formatting of tags on that site. When the room is not associated with a specific Stack Exchange site, the text used for the tag magic link receives no special processing.

#### Supported magic links in questions and answers

On main sites, only the `[tag:tag-name]` and `[meta-tag:meta-tag-name]` magic links are supported in questions and answers. The `[meta-tag:meta-tag-name]` magic links will be rendered when the post is saved, but do not display as a tag in the post preview while editing.

On meta sites, only the `[tag:tag-name]` and `[meta-tag:meta-tag-name]` magic links are supported in questions and answers.

All of the other magic links are not supported in questions and answers.

Comment: @ashleedawg - It's a community wiki, you can add things directly. (That "If you find more or more are added, please add them above." at the end...) But I've added `[mcve]`.

Comment: If curious about which magic links are used most (or ever!) and by whom, here's a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/886489/magic-link-usage-in-comments-by-users?DaysBack=30).

Comment: Hmm `[metase]` not working on [skeptics.se]...