# Is there a comment magic link for tag wikis?

Tags: feature-request, comments, tag-wiki, magic-links

When writing comments (particularly to new users) it is helpful that there are shortcuts to point people towards various site features:

- `[tour]` -> [tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour)
- `[help]` -> [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help)
- `[tag:something]` -> [something](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/something)
- (For a complete list, see: [Complete list of help center magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239707/187282).)

It would help if there were a shortcut to tag *wikis*.  For example, on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) (stats.SE), we get a lot of homework questions, and our policy is spelled out on the `[self-study]` tag's [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).  It would save a lot (of characters, typing, the hassle of navigating to the page and copying & pasting the link) if there were something like:

- `[wiki:something]`

Comment: @ShadowWizard, thanks for the edit. I didn't know that was the name.