# Retain HELP link in top bar when user has access to review queues

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar

I recently had occasion to refer to the Help Center for a stack on which I did not have review queue privileges. On such stacks, the Help icon is next to the hamburger, as shown:

[image: Top Bar with No Review]

However, on a stack on which I *do* have review queue privileges, I wished to provide a new user with a link to the Help Center's on-topic page for the stack, to assist in explaining why I flagged the question as off-topic. I had to hunt around for the link to the Help Center at the bottom of the page, because where I have review queue privileges, there's no help center link on the top bar:

[image: Top Bar with Review]

I believe that the Help Center link should remain available even if the user has review queue privileges.

Comment: Clicking the hamburger menu on the right shows a link to [help] as well.

Comment: @NVZ - One learns something every day... :)

Comment: in the dropdown as pointed by NVZ. + try to use magic links like `[ask]`, `[mcve]`, etc

Comment: Is there a list of the Magic Links and how to use them somewhere?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188238/228134

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242306/228134

Comment: The master Magic Links post is https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/207752

Comment: @robinCTS - yes, thanks - found that one linked from one of redhand's links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your wish [has been granted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301902/295232):

[image]

Comment: Might be a bug, e.g. a dev removed the rep check by mistake.

Comment: True, but I hope TPTB have realized if there's enough room for a snowflake, there's enough room for a question mark ...

Comment: Good point, lol. But now I wonder where they will put the snowflake next winterbash... ;-)

Comment: That's a big question mark ...

Comment: Considering Shog marked a related request on the Top Bar announcement as "Status Completed"... this is probably not an accident?

Comment: @Catija you meant the request I now linked to?

Comment: Precisely. I suppose that Shog could just be acting on seeing the icon as there seems to be no note anywhere else that this was intentionally implemented... but it seems like some degree of support.

Comment: I was curious where the extra votes were coming from on my answer. Looks like I have your link to thank for them in addition to Shog's edit. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

I think the current behavior is not very clear. A lot of users seem to miss the help icon in the top bar ([another example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302208/245360)).

Personally I would like to see the help button back in its place. There is enough space now to accommodate one extra button, and I've always used that button a lot. When I want to help users find the right page in the help section, I would like to have a shortcut to go there.

Also, with 500 reputation on SO, you have access to your first review queue, while 500 reputation users could benefit from the help menu since they are still quite new.

Answer (score 1):

After reading couple of comments, I regard my request as being satisfied:

- > Clicking the hamburger menu on the right shows a link to help center as well

  <sup>[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302057/retain-help-link-in-top-bar-when-user-has-access-to-review-queues#comment982370_302057)</sup>
- > try to use [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188238/152859) like [ask], [mcve], etc

  <sup>[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302057/retain-help-link-in-top-bar-when-user-has-access-to-review-queues#comment982377_302057)</sup>

(I also think it might not be a bad thing to add info about magic links to the Help Center somewhere)

Comment: There is also an excellent user script [Top-navigation choices](//stackapps.com/q/7603) which, amongst other goodies, will "Add the help button if it's not already displayed."

Answer (score 0):

I’m wondering if it wouldn’t be better to simply add an extra button across the top banner:

[image]

Even with the icon there for newer users, it’s no wonder so many of them don’t find the Help Center until a veteran user points them in that direction via a comment. Right now, it’s almost like an Easter egg – especially the Tour button.