# What happened to the tour?

Tags: support, tour

Am I missing something? I thought there used to be a tour button. I looked in the menu area, but it isn't there.

How do I find the tour?

Comment: You have enough rep to not have the (?) button in the top bar; did you want to take the [tour] again? ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I wanted to quote from the tour in a comment.  I think it is silly to not have the tour available for everyone.

Comment: That said the tour url is [siteurl/tour]

Comment: @Paparazzi use `[tour]` in comments and it will automatically converted to the link. as [tour]

Comment: cross-stie duplicate: [Where is the link to Meta and Help center in new nav?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343752/839601)

Comment: @gnat Tour and Meta are not the same

Comment: @Paparazzi It was part of the help center option in the menu, so the dup is kind-of explaining where it went.

Comment: Suggested [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301074/260388).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's linked from the footer:

[image]

Comment: Nice! Consider having that link on [SO] as well? Seems to be the only SE site without it.

Comment: @Meta agreed, there is room in the left most part, below the logo.

Comment: @Meta'sMug Hm, yeah, we'll consider it. Putting it below the logo is a non-starter, IMO, but maybe we can carve out a space elsewhere.

Comment: @Adam why not? (below the logo.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Because it'd be a rando floating link. I just don't see the aesthetics working out there at all.

Comment: @Adam I meant putting the whole "site footer menu" there, same as on all non-SO sites: Tour, Help, Chat, Contact, Feedback, Mobile. Not just the Tour.

Comment: It is linked in the footer *on some sites*. Hardly a good answer consistency-wise. Were is the consistency SO always had? I am really disappointed in recent design decisions which make the sites comprehensible.

Answer (score 10):

The tour is hidden from a certain amount of reputation I believe. If you start as a new user you will see it. Here a screenshot from Stack Overflow:

> [image]

On MSE you can find the Tour link in the footer. On Stack Overflow it just disappeared. Major inconsistency here, which is bad in my opinion.

> I think it is silly to not have the tour available for everyone.

I agree. That menu is useful to all users, not just new users. Bring it back!

Comment: @Catija nope, there is no link to Tour from help center.

Comment: You can also do achievements>badges>Informed>tour.

Answer (score 4):

In an anonymous browser window you'll find the [tour] link in the top bar; it's hidden for users with enough rep, so it'll show up if you're not logged in.

[image: anonymous login top bar (?) button]

Alternatively, you can duplicate your current browser tab, go to the site's home page, then add `/tour` to the URL address, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> - and you're there!

Comment: Looks like it's around 2k-4k rep, and I'd bet it's 2k as that icon is replaced with 'review queues' for me on sites where I have >2k rep (Code Review and Stack Overflow), so I'd think that at 2,000 rep it becomes the review queues link.

Comment: @202_accepted it should be 500 rep. (Minimum required to review.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard As it turns out, *for all sites except **this** one*, that's true. Just checked with my other profiles, and *this* site is the 2k limit for that feature. (We're both right, apparently.) See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges vs. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges Bizarre that they differ, but that explains much more.

Comment: @202_accepted nothing bizarre, MSE simply has no first posts and late answers queues, hence the minimum rep is 2000.