# What happened to the "tour" button?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

*This has been reposted from [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10243/80336), since I noticed the issue is more than* just *this site. This issue is also happening on this super-meta SE.*

I believe this picture should help understand the issue at hand :

[image: Picture showing the connexion]
<sup>Tour button? Toouurr buuttooon?</sup>

I cannot find the button in the header to reach the tour anymore, even though it is still accessible by direct access and existing links (like [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) or [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour)). This happens both logged in and logged out, on meta and on main, on mobile phone and on PC, for a total of 4 web browsers tested and 3 different devices (or 4? I don't recall). It is not reachable through the help-center, either<sup>1</sup>. The only place which I can access it is from the footer on the main site only, which is very far from being convenient, both [UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience) and [UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface) wise.

Since we can still technically reach the page and the button is quite important to newcomers, I currently believe it's a bug. So what happened to the easy-to-access tour button? Any fix in the foreseeable future?

---

<sup>1 : I put emphasis on all this because I did have access to the tour button from the header before. This is not a duplicate of this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302208/what-happened-to-the-tour) posted 6 years ago.</sup>

Comment: Well, some people have better eyes than me . I was surprised to find nothing [recent around the "Tour" word](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=Tour&searchOn=3) or the similar questions given by the A.I. when I copied this post. I'll leave this post in case someone make the same kind of research I did. And to highlight it's quite important, too.

Comment: Looking into it.  Seems like something got pushed that unintentionally borked things.  Wasn't a deliberate choice, and I'm looking into how we get it rolled back, but yesterday was a little... busy.