# Help develop the site and community knowledge base in your language

Tags: discussion, international-sites

I think everyone agrees that it is great to have a lot of technology Q&A. In this way, anyone can quickly understand how to use a technology. The Stack Exchange engine is a quite complicated tool as well. Understanding how the site works is difficult. In addition, there are many subtleties of the system, which have no analogues, which means that if you do not accidentally see a button somewhere, then you could miss some of the site’s  interesting features.

Although all international sites already have FAQ sections, I would like to emphasise their importance once again and ask you to help your community with creating new ones.

#### FAQs on Meta Stack Exchange

MSE has a great [community knowledge base about the system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq). I think, most of these questions will be of use to each international site. I picked up a list of FAQs ([in an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319025/274323)), which we translated into the Russian language. These FAQs reveal the most important aspects of the site. Please translate them for your community if they seem interesting to you.

#### Your personal notes

Often new users not only have questions about the technical side of the system; for them, FAQs about an unique social contract of a particular community are extremely important. If you see that over and over that new users are facing the same non-technical problem, please describe it in a FAQ-like question on your meta.

Let's help your colleagues understand how Stack Overflow in your language works with FAQs.

---

Related:

- [¿Sabes inglés, quieres aportar a la comunidad de SOes y no sabes cómo? ¡Traduce un FAQ!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1380/10)

Answer (score 4):

If your community has translated other FAQs that are not listed in any language below, please add them!

### FAQs translated into the Russian language

#### Blog

- [Improved Tagging](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/09/improved-tagging/)
- [The Stack Overflow Question Lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/17/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/)
- [Community Promotion Ads](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/31/community-promotion-ads/)
- [Supporting Community Conferences](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/04/supporting-community-conferences/)
- [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)
- [A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- [Reputation and Historical Archives](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/)
- [A Recipe to Promote your Site](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/23/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/)

#### FAQ

- [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)
- [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right)
- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)
- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)
- [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)
- [Complete list of help center magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239707/complete-list-of-help-center-magic-links)
- [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)
- [What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)
- [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)
- [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)
- [How do I search for questions with (or without) specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-or-without-specific-tags)
- [What do "watched tags" and "ignored tags" do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-watched-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)
- [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)
- [How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)
- [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)
- [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)
- [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)
- [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
- [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes)
  [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)
- [When should I vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote)
- [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work)
- [What is the weekly newsletter? Who composes them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121630/what-is-the-weekly-newsletter-who-composes-them)
- [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)
- [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)
- [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)
- [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)
- [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)
- [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do)
- [My account has been temporarily suspended; what does that mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125268/my-account-has-been-temporarily-suspended-what-does-that-mean)
- [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated)
- [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)
- [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)
- [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)
- [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)
- [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)
- [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)
- [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 4):

On Stack Overflow en español we have our own threads about FAQ translations:

- [¿Sabes inglés, quieres aportar a la comunidad de SOes y no sabes cómo? ¡Traduce un FAQ!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1380/65) (translation: *Do you know English, do you want to contribute to the SOes community and don't know how? Translate a FAQ!*)
  This thread has a list of FAQ in English. Those that are already translated FAQs are struckthrough with a link to the translation.
- [FAQ para sitios de Stack Exchange](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/65) (translation: *FAQ about Stack Exchange Sites*)
  This thread has a list of FAQ in Spanish. Those threads have the [faq](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) tag.

---

Translated/adapted SO blog articles

- A moderation theory -> [Una teoría de moderación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227/65)
- Attribution required -> [Atribución requerida](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3695/65)
- Vote early, vote often -> [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2209/65)

Threads related to a SO blog articles

- Community Promotion Ads -> [Anuncios de promoción de la comunidad - 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1185/65)
- Supporting Community Conferences -> [Objetivos 2017 ¿Encuentros locales?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1371/65)

Comment: Looks cool! Could you please tell me how big is the intersection between what is translated on SOru and what does on SOes?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I'm not good to make that kind of guesses. What about if we add ES, JA, PT and/or RU next to each translated item on [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/289691)? (even better if that letters are links to the corresponding translated FAQ)

Comment: Sounds really interesting. I think in general FAQs in English are for English-speaking folks. They do not need the Ru (ES/PT/JA) version of the page and might be upset. Could you please tell me how do you see the approach?

Comment: Even than English is the mandatory language on Meta SE, it is about all the SE network, not just about the English sites, so in consideration of international users, specially those that feel more confortable by reading on their own language it would be very nice to facilitate them a way to find those posts that are already translated, and, IMHO, a small link next to an items on a list of items isn't disruptive at all.

Comment: Maybe you should start by making a try on the [sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/289691) rather than doing that directly on [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/289691)

Comment: I decided to start this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319169/289691). At this time I added links to the Spanish versions.

Comment: Thank you! Let see what will happen. I'll ping SOru community about the initiative.