# New help pages needed for the latest feature additions/changes (follow, bookmarks, thanks)

Tags: feature-request, comments, help-center

**Problem**

Some time ago there was a change to the icons displayed next to a question, and [the favourite icon was replaced by a bookmark icon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347558/398063).

In addition [we now have a "follow" link underneath questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/398063).

However, there is nothing in any of the site help pages explaining what either of the above do. It would be useful if we had a couple of new help pages:

1. One that explains what all these icons around questions and answers do when you click on them.

   For "Bookmark this question" the explanation should include how a user finds their bookmarks.
2. Another that explains what the "follow" link does (and how to find posts you are following).

   Note: there is already [a help page that explains the "flag" link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). For consistency we should have help pages for the other links.

**Justification**: we can link to the help pages when assisting new users in comments. For example I have an [AutoReview comment](https://stackapps.com/q/2116):

> Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](https://$SITEURL$/privileges/vote-up) the question. You can also "bookmark" it or "follow" it (which will notify you of any new answers).

I would like to be able to link to help pages about "bookmark" and "follow" in my comment.

**Bonus Feature Request**: please also add [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239707/complete-list-of-help-center-magic-links) for the new help pages.

Comment: There already is a help center article (on SO) for reactions. Https://stackoverflow.com/help/reactions

Comment: @Catija Thanks, removed that footnote.

Comment: I'll make y'all a deal. You create the content so that it matches the existing style, I'll make a help center page. No promises on the magic links, though

Comment: @Catija I've added suggested help text for "Follow" as an answer below. I've also [found a bug and reported it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350053/267099)

Comment: @Catija Another answer added for `/help/bookmark`

Answer (score 5):

#### Suggested text for a new help page /help/bookmark

**What does it mean if a question or answer is "bookmarked"?**

You can bookmark any question by clicking on the bookmark icon just below and to the left of the
question title. Clicking on the icon a second time will unbookmark the question.

> [image]

Bookmarking a question will allow you to find it easily again later.

**How do I find questions I have bookmarked?**

There is a tab for Bookmarks on the user profile activity page.

This tab provides a listing of bookmarked questions, with standard sorts, and the ability to unbookmark from the listing.

The bookmarks tab on your profile also has a counter indicating how many of your bookmarked questions have received answers
since you last viewed that tab.

When you click on the tab, recently changed questions will be highlighted.
"Changed" includes comments on or edits to the question and new or edited answers.
This is a way to get updates on questions that you yourself didn't ask.

> [image]

If you prefer to get inbox notifications when questions or answers are modified you may prefer to "Follow" <sup>1</sup> a question or answer instead.

If you follow a post, you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question),
comments, edits, and notices.

<sup>1. Link to be added to the new /help/follow page</sup>

Answer (score 4):

#### Suggested text for a new help page `/help/follow`

**What does it mean if a question or answer is "followed"?**

You can follow any question or answer (that you did not author) by clicking on the [follow] button that is shown in the
menu immediately below the post (alongside the [share] button):

> [image: Get updates on questions and answers]

After you have followed a post, you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a
question), comments, edits, and notices. You will not receive notifications for any action that you performed.

**How do I find questions or answers that I have followed?**

There is a tab "Following" on the user profile activity page.

This tab provides a listing of followed questions and answers, with standard sorts, and the ability to unfollow from the listing.

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Answer updated as [more dropdown Follow is now status declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network/350053#350053)