# Add magic link to "someone answers"

Tags: feature-request, magic-links

Perhaps `[help/someone-answers]`. Very handy for posting in a comment on a question if the OP doesn't seem to understand how SE works vis-a-vis answers. Ideally the generated text would be the title of the target page (currently, "What should I do when someone answers my question?").

---

*(Re "magic links", see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188238/134069) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000).)*

Comment: I've always preferred the respective [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/162011) for this purpose, but I agree that the help center would be better for a magic link.

Comment: I wonder why this is taking too long..