# Add magic link for MCVE

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, magic-links

Perhaps `[help/mcve]` (which would link to `/help/mcve` on sites that have it), it comes up a *lot* on SO. Ideally the autotext would be "MCVE" so a sample usage would be:

> It's not clear from your question quite where the problem might be, can you create an [mcve]?

which would render as (on SO):

> It's not clear from your question quite where the problem might be, can you create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

---

*(Re "magic links", see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188238/134069) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000).)*

Comment: The hell is that anyhow?  Should just shorten it to [mcve], you know.

Comment: @Won't: Yeah, I like `[mcve]` better, it's just `[help/mcve]` is in keeping with the others. Note that we're not comparing `[help/mcve]` with `/help/mcve`, though, we're comparing `[help/mcve]` to `[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)` So it really is a lot shorter.

Comment: Just saying, shortest link now is `[MCVE](/help/mcve)`

Comment: @nicael: I've previously tried that and had it not work, so I just tried it on SO and it didn't work, so I commented here, and it **did** work, so I tried it on SO again and it **did** work. I guess I must be prone to typos! So thanks, that's absolutely easier than what I'm doing now. `[mcve]` would be even better.

Comment: If there won't be any response, I could write it as an answer because this link is shorter than yours :) And, btw, probably you tried `[MCVE](help/mcve)` instead of `[MCVE](/help/mcve)` so it didn't work.

Comment: No, it isn't shorter. I'm looking for `[mcve]` or `[help/mcve]`, both of which are shorter (and less fiddly!) than `[MCVE](/help/mcve)`.

Comment: Ok. I mean shorter than one you have tried before :)

Comment: [The same has been requested on meta.pt.so](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2357/sugest%C3%A3o-de-um-novo-magic-link). I left a link to your feature request there, hoping to get this more supporters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/164200) this has been implemented on Stack Overflow.

Typing `[mcve]` in a comment will expand to a link.

Comment: It has! Just tested it on SO. Yay!