# Can we get a hotlink for the "On Topic" page in the Help Center?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

I know there's [another post saying the On Topic page is too hard to find in the new Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183213/on-topic-list-is-too-hard-to-find-in-the-new-help-center), but that's not what I'm asking. I want a hotlink for comments that goes directly to [the On Topic page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), like the `[FAQ]` one went to the FAQ page (and now goes to the Help page). I don't know exactly what we should call it, that can be up for discussion. `[On Topic]`? I'd just like a quick-and-easy way to continue to point users to a list of what is and isn't on topic for a given site, which is what I used to use the `[FAQ]` link to do. But that won't really work anymore, since it doesn't go directly to an On Topic list, so I'd appreciate another way to achieve the same functionality.

Thoughts?

Comment: The more often a resource is likely to need pointing to, the better the case is for it being easy to point to...and on-topic posting looks like something with a wide potential audience.  This seems completely reasonable.

Comment: For what it's worth, `[faq#questions]` ([faq#questions]) should do the trick until this is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now have a magic link to the on-topic page: `[help/on-topic]` links to "What topics can I ask about here?" (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

For a list of additional magic links, see [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188238/166017) on [Replace [faq] magiclink with [help]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183131/replace-faq-magiclink-with-help)