# Can we explain what the pins mean in the Help Center?

Tags: feature-request, help-center

I read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183318/241700) and it is marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

There seems to have been no action taken from the "completion"

From the answer on related post:

> I think people who have spent time on traditional forums expect a pin icon to mean that a post is "sticky", or always at the top, which is what these pinned items are. **However, we also added a sentence in the hero image on the help center landing page that instructs users to begin by reading the pinned articles first.** This should make it pretty clear that the pinned articles are the most important.

The bold part of the answer above **never** seemed to come to fruition.

So again -- Can these pins **please** be clarified on the **actual** [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) as to what they mean?

Comment: What is the "hero image on the help center landing page?"  I guess what they're referring to is *"New to Stack Overflow? Find out everything you need to get started by taking the tour. If you still have questions, **come back and check out the pinned articles.**"*

Comment: Wow... I did not even see that.... So unreadable...

Comment: Well, my eyes have always glossed over that text, but the meaning of the pins seems crystal clear to me.  They're the important ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to close this as a duplicate, since the question is based on an incorrect assumption that the previous question's answer was wrong.

However, even if it wasn't a dupe, I'd decline this; while we occasionally see users being uncertain of what the pins mean, it's a pretty common visual metaphor on the Internet, and it's not worth creating a whole separate page in the help center to explain it.

Comment: Can you at least embolden the text that explains what they are doing there?