# Why does Server Fault's new help system de-emphasize the professional audience?

Tags: discussion, serverfault, help-center

The new help system doesn't work at all on ServerFault.com.

Only IT people know the expression 'stack overflow', thus 99% of new Stack Overflow users know it's a coding site. Unfortunately the same can't be said for 'server faults' because my cleaner (thinks she) knows what a server is - thus we get a lot of wildly inappropriate questions about home routers, gaming etc.

When we had a simple FAQ people could read it and the very first line explained we're there for professional sysadmin questions. Now this is buried beneath a generic, undiscussed and mandated 'help' system that does quite the opposite. It's no surprise then that throughout June we've had to close or migrate a lot more questions than usual - we can't even ask them to take a quick look at the FAQ either.

So why the iron-fist approach? I asked this question on meta.sf only to be told that all discussions around this decision were to be addressed here - is that a new policy too, that all SE-wide discussions/announcements are to be on meta.so?

I'm aware that SO had an enormous amount of users compared to SF but we still have a lot. None of the older, more established users, or mods for that matter, are happy about these changes and I know the mods don't feel like they're being listened to.

Comment: I'm a Stack Overflow user, and I read this post.

Comment: Meta.so has always been the main discussion area for SE changes since it was the first site. SE as a whole is supposed to eventually have a meta site of its own and meta.so will be only for stackoverflow.

Comment: [Link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange) for Josh's comment about M.SO and Meta.StackExchange. Asked just under 18 (?!) months ago.

Comment: Thanks Josh - but that means users for the other sites need to keep a close on on meta.so for issues that will affect them. Couldn't there be a link post on affected site's metas? at least we'd know about them then without having to manually search, on a per-user basis, periodically for notices. It's a very pre-web kind of approach, nail news on the town-square board.

Comment: [Here's another link on the subject](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/), from the SO blog.

Comment: @Chopper3 enough to track the [meta-tag:featured] tag on regular basis, whatever get that tag means it's affecting the whole network. There won't be more than a few each month or so, so no big deal as far as I can see.

Comment: Note that help/on-topic is mod-editable.

Comment: Thanks Sha, I just don't see what's wrong with a site-specific one-line meta post saying "hey guys, we're discussing something that might affect you over here", that's not hard is it?

Comment: @Manishearth I did not know that, thank you - shame I gave up bing a mod on SF :)

Comment: @Chopper3 For a moment there I thought you were Iain (who I knew had recently stepped down), but then I remembered that Iain changed his grav. This choppertar business is confusing.

Comment: I have a fair amount of things to say but I do want to first say that you didn't actually have to bring the discussion from Meta SF over here. We may have initiated the discussion here but that's no reason that the thread on Meta Server Fault was inappropriate - it was actually pretty appropriate since that's where most of the rest of the SF folk will see it.

Comment: @Manishearth - I'm the Chopper in the choppertar - I was away from the board for about 8 months dealing with cancer - came back the *day* of these changes in fact!

Comment: He's busted cancer and now he's here to bust balls.

Comment: @Chopper3 Yeah, I figured that out, but you had segfaulted my brain for a moment there.

Comment: You and your coding terms ;)

Comment: @GraceNote: Several closely related things have been brought up on mSF recently and I even pointed you and Jaydles at them. Jaydles even went so far as to propose a hangout (whatever that means). Unfortunately y'all haven't seen fit to say anything more... Seems to me that the only place to grab SE's attention is here on mSO.

Comment: I've posted a response to this [over on Server Fault's Meta here](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5600/why-the-major-faq-help-change/5631#5631).

Comment: @Iain, sincere apologies if you felt ignored. It wasn't my intention.  Since I'd suggested the discussion, and at the time, some of you didn't seem available, when I tabled it, I thought I was postponing my concern, not one of yours - my bad.

Comment: @Iain - *precisely* my point, couldn't have put it better myself

Comment: @Jaydles: I don't feel ignored but I was disappointed to hear (when I asked a SF mod) that nothing had progressed. GraceNote's comment above (about using SF meta) does not match my experience. Since Phil made this question there has been more SE employee activity on mSF than there has been in months (if you ignore the recent election).

Comment: @Iain, understood. I'm reaching out to the SF mod team right now to follow up on the pro-level restriction issues SF has.

Comment: Similar issue raised on AskDifferent http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/the-page-http-apple-stackexchange-com-help-on-topic-needs-to-be-more-prominent the on-topic definite  should be at the top of the help page

Answer (score 3):

Server Fault does have a new FAQ page, but it's not /help.

It's [the About page](https://serverfault.com/about) (which anon users get linked to in a big, shiny  button)

[image]

The new About explains the target audience, introduces a user to the site, and has bullet points (yay) for the "what's on topic"/"what's off topic" bits. The target audience and bullet points are mod editable.

The new /help pages are meant as a reference; to link to when explaining something to a new user.

Comment: So they replaced the faq link with help, then replaced the faq with about? I see. Sure. I'm sure that makes sense to *somebody*.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/faq redirects to http://serverfault.com/help not http://serverfault.com/about

Comment: That page doesn't place much emphasis on what is on topic, which is the thing we are having trouble with over there.  Yes, it is near the top, but the wording is pretty weak and it actually took me a moment to find.

Comment: @ChrisS I meant that the old faq is _functionally_ equivalent to the new /about

Comment: In any event, it's nearly impossible to find the on-topic relevancy on those pages.

Comment: @ScottPack A new user is expected to read through it. From what I see, the old FAQ was something very few people would read (it was quite long). The new about has less text and more pictoral explanations. It's also more prominent to anon users. There's a far greaterchance people will actually read it. In the event that you have to _link_ to the list of what's on topic, use http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Manishearth - the first line said "this site is for professional sysadmins, not for home stuff" (I'm paraphrasing obviously :) ) - that helped, seriously, just that.

Comment: @Manishearth: Even as a long time user I've read through it and have a helluvatime figuring out what's acceptable and what isn't. Keep in mind, this entire conversation is regarding the on-topic topics. On the old FAQ that was a concise bullet list at the very top. It's a struggle to find it in /help.

Comment: @ScottPack Yes, because /help is no longer for casual reading, it's for linking to. And when you link to [this](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), you get the bullet list on top :)

Comment: I do understand how it's confusing, trust me, I [had similar objections initially](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center/183132#183132). However, I noticed that /about is something people actually will _read_, as opposed to the old /faq.

Comment: The very first two statements on the About page are contradictory. On the left it says "for professionals". Under "Here's how it works", it says "Anybody can ask a question". I have seen people reference that sentence repeatedly in the past week, claiming that we could not talk about a target audience because it clearly says anybody can ask.

Comment: @JennyD There's a _target_ audience and then there's the _allowed_ audience. Anyone can ask, but the site will always try to target the professionals.

Comment: @Manishearth: It's too confusing and the (apparent) contradiction leads to way too much drama.

Comment: @Iain Hmm, true. You may want to ask for a wording change in a separate feature request.

Comment: @Manishearth Having to repeatedly inform people that just because you *can* ask a question here doesn't mean you *should*, means that the "allowed" audience is driving the targeted audience away. If you want a site for professionals (and a lot of us do), then it should be made clear from the start what the site is and isn't. The latest changes in faq/help/about have resulted in a reduction in question quality. That means that the changes have failed to achieve their purpose - how else would you measure whether a change is successful or not?

Comment: @JennyD examples? data? Till now I wasn't told of either. I understand your concerns, again, I suggest you request for a change of wording.

Comment: @JennyD: Are you suggesting that the ability to ask questions on Server Fault should be restricted to people who can prove that they are "professionals"? Because that's offensive and will _never_ happen on this network. Indeed, anyone can ask. The intended audience is clearly stated. **There is no problem here.**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit with the greatest of respect, there **IS** a problem on Server Fault with the quality of questions being asked. To judge that Jenny, a SF regular, is being offensive by talking about the issue when you've barely visited SF yourself *is also somewhat offensive* - You appear to be affected by the typical mindset that I've seen in a lot of Stack Overflow users when an issue from the other sites appears here: You're confusing the fact that *you* aren't having a problem with whether or not the problem exists.

Comment: And, again, it highlights the problem with mSO being *the* place to go. mSF means nothing, and mSO doesn't really care about anyone who isn't SO.

Comment: @Dan No it doesn't. Being a Physics.SE user (I joined SO much later), I do care about the issues of non-SO sites, I've been quite vocal about that at times. And so have other users. Though I agree that MSO de facto assumes that SO is the only site in the network at times.

Comment: And whatever your quality issues are, disallowing users on the basis of their expertise is not something _any_ SE site will do. Sure, you can filter their content, but explicitly disallowing them is something else. This has nothing to do with SO-vs-SF. This is how the network is. I understand that you have quality issues, but disallowing (as opposed to dissuading) non-experts is not the solution, imho.

Comment: "And whatever your quality issues are, disallowing users on the basis of their expertise is not something any SE site will do." --  actually the "charter" of SF has always been that it's a site for *IT Professionals*. Check the description in your own SE account list: "Q&A for professional system and network administrators". Now I personally interpret that as referring to the standard of *questions* rather than the standard of the *person asking them*, but either way the standard is there, and right now we **do** have a problem because the site's scope isn't being presented properly...

Comment: @RobM: How rude. No, I'm not confused at all. I am well aware that some site that I don't visit can have a problem even if it doesn't personally affect me. I am not suggesting that there is no _question quality_ problem -- we have one on SO, too. What I'm saying is that the FAQ/help text is just fine the way it is, because once you start going down the road of cutting certain people out of the ability to post questions, just because one or two people deem them to be insufficiently qualified, that is a _very_ dangerous road to follow. _That's_ where the offence lies. Use the review tools.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Use the review tools" -- the review tools that do nothing to stop people asking questions that are unanswerable or off topic in the first place, thus wasting their time and providing a bad experience of stack exchange to them as new users? *Those* review tools? How exactly do they solve the problem again?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No offence, but you seem to have a massive misconception of what ServerFault is, how it works and who it's designed for. The whole point of ServerFault, and it's success hinges on this, is that it separates "users" from "administrators". We're for professionals, not for users and user based questions do not belong there.

Comment: @rob Yes, I'm aware of the description. Check  the description of other sites  too. They're similar. That's the _target_ audience, but in no way does that imply that you get to become an exclusive club. I am not a sysad, I am a physics student who programs (and is currently tussling with server issues) in my free time. You're telling me that I can't set foot there? That's ... quite discriminatory. The point here is that __you should discriminate on the basis of _posts_, not users__.

Comment: @dan so, as a user I cannot ask a near-professional level question about server management?

Comment: [security.se]  is a good example here. They are also for "professonals". I'm not a professional. Yet I [participate there](http://security.stackexchange.com/users/7497/manishearth). Both asking and answering. I don't think I bring the quality down.

Comment: These ServerFault "representatives" are mired in the erroneous notion that they have the right to discriminate against people before they've even posted anything, and declare whether they can or cannot make that post. No way to argue against that logic.

Comment: Unfortunately, `These ServerFault "representatives"` do hold the same opinion as the majority of the most active high-rep users. The simple fact is, ServerFault has already lost two high-rep users and a moderator has *resigned* over the level of "professionalism" shown on the site. If it continues to get low-quality questions more higher-rep and expereinced users will leave, eventually leaving ServerFault as the Yahoo! Answers site where the accepted answer isn't always the best.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit *These ServerFault "representatives" are mired in the erroneous notion that they have the right to discriminate against people before they've even posted anything* -- assuming you're lumping me in with those "representatives", I said quite clearly that "I personally interpret that as referring to the standard of questions rather than the standard of the person asking them". I suggest that before yourself and Manishearth worry about the speck in my eyes when it comes to mis-interpreting things, you might both care to do something about the logs in your own.

Comment: **"You're telling me that I can't set foot there? That's ... quite discriminatory. The point here is that you should discriminate on the basis of posts, not users."** -- Oh. You mean exactly like what *I already said I do* (and several times in the past on mSF too, btw)? If you're going to try and pick something to  accuse me of discrimination over, you might try picking something where I'm not actually working in the way you think I should, otherwise you might look a little foolish.

Comment: @rob I understand that, however the topoc of this entire discussion was the apparent conflict between "anyone can ask", and "this site is for professionals". I understand that you feel that it's for the standard of question, amd I agree. My comment was not exacly directed to _you_, though I should have used "they" or "one" instead of "you". Sorry about that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why, then, was ServerFault created with and for a specific target audience, if pointing to a specific target audience is offensive?

Comment: @light, everyone And can we please keep this civil? We won't get anywhere otherwise.

Comment: @jenny SF can point all they want. However, it shouldn't show users the door just because who they are.

Comment: @Manishearth Which is why we've consistently talked about **question** quality, not user quality - but with the added point that it's really hard to ask a question that is useful for the target audience if you're not even close to that audience. It can be done, but it's far from easy or common.

Comment: @jenny yes, and my point was simple: there is no conflict between "a site for professionals" and  "anyone can ask". The comments following that  comment made it look like  (to me, and probably Lightness) the SF community was taking that very literally and using it to justify disallowing users. That's when the discussion bombed. If all of us are in agreement thag sf doesn't want to/shouldn't disallow users from the outset, can we continue constructively now?

Comment: We're actually having similar problems on Physics. One possible solution is to tighten up your quality standards, amd  aggressively close/downvote posts off the main page. This makes the site _look_ moreprofessional as only good posts stay. Your main page was a mess last I checked.

Comment: (I actually have a few half thought-out feature requests  regarding the main page that ought to  help solve this. I'll post 'em tomorrow)

Comment: At this point there is nothing I can say that will be even remotely productive, so I'm bowing out.

Comment: Aight, good luck with your quality issue. Sorry about this whole argument :s

Comment: Well, this was a good use of time.

Comment: **Your main page was a mess last I checked.** -- No arguments there. Sadly we get panned for closing... sorry, we're supposed to call it *putting on hold* aren't we ;-)... too many questions. We get accused of being elitist and discriminatory when we try to 'enforce' those standards and that brings us back to how unhelpful it is for both us *and new visitors* that the help/faq pages are  vague and contradictory.

Comment: @rob You shouldn't get panned for closing user-pov (ie not sysad-pov) questions. I can understand how you may get panned for closing basic sysad-kiddie questions, though. In this case I do feel that sf should be allowed to draw a line of "too basic", as SO exists and these can be asked there (i'm _usually_ against filtering by level, but the existence of SO changes things ). I suggest (a) you hammer out if and which basic qs get closed on meta, and (b) you suggest an alternative wording for the /about. :)

Comment: @rob btw, link to the panning? I have some ideas/meta posts that i'll flesh out tomorrow, however I need details :)

Comment: @Manishearth: It's not your problem.

Comment: @Manishearth Links to some panning: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186838/why-does-server-faults-new-help-system-de-emphasize-the-professional-audience#comment575298_186844) [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186838/why-does-server-faults-new-help-system-de-emphasize-the-professional-audience#comment574991_186844) [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186838/why-does-server-faults-new-help-system-de-emphasize-the-professional-audience#comment575168_186844)

Comment: And [4](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186838/why-does-server-faults-new-help-system-de-emphasize-the-professional-audience#comment575298_186844) [5](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186838/why-does-server-faults-new-help-system-de-emphasize-the-professional-audience#comment575389_186844). I think that demonstrates the issue well enough...

Comment: @iain Actually no, since I have similar issues on Physics, it _is_ my problem. The sf business gave me some ideas, that's all.

Comment: @r.tanner.f Not sure if you're serious, but I was asking about the "don't close too many questions" panning mentioned by RobM. The argument in this thread is over, drop it.

Comment: FAQ and About and Help links aside, how about just adding a tagline below the logo in the header? Then it would be visible to all users all the time (save maybe for mobile users with the current layout, but maybe it can be changed to accommodate a few more pixels of height in the header)? Something like "The Professional System Administrator Q&A Site" or whatever, preferably cooler, if you can do that without sacrificing information content.

Comment: @tripleee That would work (That sentence structure could be reshuffled a bit though)