# What happen to Cross Validated faq page

Tags: support, stack-exchange

When I tried to access [Cross Validated faq](https://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) page, It get redirect to [about](https://stats.stackexchange.com/about) page. So my question is : What happen to Cross Validated faq page.

Comment: [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center) happened.

Comment: @Oded thanks for answer....

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from [Oded comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center). It is due to the maintenance. I had access faq through /help.

> This is now live on all Stack Exchange sites. You can access it at /help or by clicking the "help" link in the top nav or footer of any page.